# Text replacing in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, replace

I am currently working on some code that gets the text (from the cms) in a textblock and replaces so called 'dynamic words' that are defined in the CMS, so when you click a 'dynamic word' it gives you an alert. I now have this code but it doesn't work and it did work with hardcoded text instead of dynamic words from the CMS.
Can anyone see where the problem is here?

For extra info leave an message ( For example if you need to know what an specified console.log gives back :) )

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { TextBlock } from './ArticleBodyText.styles';

export const ArticleBodyText = ({ item, dynamic_words }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const el = document.getElementById('this-text');
    const text = el.innerHTML;
    dynamic_words.map(word => {
      const dynamic_word = word.word?.[0].text;
      const newText = text.replace(
        `/\b${dynamic_word}\b/g`,
        `<span class='dynamic-word'>${dynamic_word}</span>`
      );
      el.innerHTML = newText;
      const spans = el.querySelectorAll('.dynamic-word');
      for (let i = 0; i < spans.length; i += 1) {
        spans[i].addEventListener(
          'click',
          function () {
            if (this.innerHTML === dynamic_word) {
              alert('You clicked a dynamic word!');
            }
          },
          false
        );
      }
    });
  });

  return item?.primary?.body_text.map(bodytext => (
    <TextBlock
      id="this-text"
      key={bodytext.text}
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: bodytext.text }}
    />
  ));
};
```

EDIT:
Working version:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { TextBlock } from './ArticleBodyText.styles';

export const ArticleBodyText = ({ item, dynamic_words }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const el = document.getElementById('this-text');
    const text = el.innerHTML;
    const newText = text.replace(/\bte\b/g, "<span class='dynamic-word'>te</span>");
    el.innerHTML = newText;
    const spans = el.querySelectorAll('.dynamic-word');
    for (let i = 0; i < spans.length; i += 1) {
      spans[i].addEventListener(
        'click',
        function () {
          if (this.innerHTML === 'te') {
            alert('Je hebt op een dynamic word geklikt!');
          }
        },
        false
      );
    }
  });

  return item?.primary?.body_text.map(bodytext => (
    <TextBlock
      id="this-text"
      key={bodytext.text}
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: bodytext.text }}
    />
  ));
};
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide the prior 'working' version and also describe in what way it is no longer working.  You seem to have some nested objects and arrays there we don't understand the structure of, plus a lot of optional chaining which is going to result in 'undefined' values when absent.

Comment: I found that the problem is here: ```const newText = text.replace(/\bte\b/g```, but how can i replace 'te' with the dynamic_word const?

Comment: You want to replace "te" inside this span tag with dynamic_word const 
`"<span class='dynamic-word'>te</span>"` ?

Comment: No, I want to replace the 'te' in the replace regex with the dynamic_word const

Comment: const word = "something";

const newText = `/\b${word}\b/g `; This newText has to be inside template literals

Comment: I've added in the comment, but it is formatting it as codeblock

Comment: Make sure to add the pattern inside template literals

Comment: Already tried, not working, so weird :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way you can create dynamic regex

```js
const word = "something";
const sentence = "This is something";

let first = "\\b",
  second = "\\b";

const regex = new RegExp(first + word + second, "g");

const newSent = sentence.replace(regex, "Inder");
console.log(newSent);
```

Answer (score 1):

`replace` expects a regular expression or a string (exact match, not a string that looks like a regular expression).  You will need to create a regex from a template literal:

```
const oldText = "the sly brown fox is sly"
const dynamic_word = "sly"
const newText = oldText.replaceAll(
  new RegExp(`\\b${dynamic_word}\\b`, 'g'),
  `<span class='dynamic-word'>${dynamic_word}</span>`
);

console.log(newText)
```

Note:

- The `\b` word break flag needs to be escaped in the template literal
- You must use the `g` flag or it will only replace the first occurrence

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, I changed it to:

```
const dynamic_word = word.word?.[0].text;
      const first = '\\b';
      const second = '\\b';
      const regex = new RegExp(first + dynamic_word + second, 'g');
      const newText = text.replace(regex, `<span class="dynamic-word">${dynamic_word}</span>`);
```